# What do uints initiate to?

Tags: ethereum, solidity

In solidity what do numbers initiate to assuming we just call a plain number.

```
uint256 plainNumber
```

I understand it's zero. But what I'm asking for, is there a way to detect if that number has been set by the compiler or a user variable. For example...

```
uint256 plainNumber;
***some code and we continue***
plainNumber = 0;
```

Is there any way to detect if I set the plainNumber or if it was simply initialized at zero? Any special protocol?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my experience, you cannot know if the value is 0 because it's the inital state or if it is 0 because of 'you'.

One 'solution' would be to use a struct of this kind, and set the `isSet` bool when you change the plainNumber value :

```
struct myPlainNumber {
    uint256 plainNumber
    bool isSet
}
```

Comment: So I figured. My use case is very peculiar since I was trying to save on contract size. However, I have found another way for my particular use case